# building reactjs app with cordova

Tags: cordova, reactjs

Just want to test and see if the build from create-react-app will work with Cordova, and found that it came up with the blank screen. Has anyone tried this?

```
$> create-react-app temp
$> cd temp
$> npm run build
$> cd ..
$> cordova create cordova-temp
```

copy the content from temp > build folder into cordova-temp > www

```
$> cd cordova-temp
$> cordova run ios
```

this is how to produce this problem. Or perhaps I'm missing something. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your project homepage value to ./ in `package.json` for this to work with CRA.

e.g.:

`"homepage": "./"`